# Can We Control MFA Frequency?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can we control the frequency with which a user needs to perform the MFA step?  i.e. only force MFA once per day?

I don't see anything under [the MFA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa) for this.

I'm thinking the answer is no, and we need this UserVoice item, [MFA Remembering Device](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16104154-mfa-remembering-device), to be completed, correct?

Comment: Do you want to suppress MFA for all future logins by the same user (regardless of browser, IP address, etc.)?

Comment: I'm thinking force MFA once per N days if it is the same browser.  @ChrisPadgett

Answer (score 1):

You can allow users to "remember authentication on devices they trust" in the Azure portal and set the number of days from 1 to 60. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#remember-multi-factor-authentication-for-trusted-devices) for details.

[image: remember MFA]

Comment: Hmmm, that applies to B2C?

Comment: Hmm I will try to reproduce tomorrow and confirm.

Comment: Hi  Joel - did you get a chance to try it?

Comment: Hi Joel - did you get a chance to try it?